# Creación de vista sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta, y es que intento crear una vista mediante el siguiente script

```
Create view Reporte_de_Empleados
as
select * from Empleado order by Cargo desc
```

pero... el problema es que no me deja crearla y me lanza un mensaje relacionado a "Order by" que es invalido:

```
Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Reporte_de_Empleados, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 322]
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

pero.... necesito que se ordenen de esa manera.

alguna sugerencia ?

Comment: Una sugerencia? Haz caso al mensaje de error. No se puede utiliar la cláusula order by en la definición de una vista, al menos no como lo tienes. Sugerencia #2: Crea la vista sin el `Order By`. Sugerencia #3, si quieres ordenar los datos, `select * from dbo.vista_reporte_de_empleados order by Cargo` => Utiliza el order by cuando llamas a la vista.

Answer (score 3):

Las vistas, al igual que las tablas, no tienen un orden establecido. El orden se tiene que definir en cada consulta puesto que cada consulta es distinta.

Por lo tanto, NO necesitas que se ordenen en la vista. Necesitas que se ordenen en la consulta que llama la vista.